# A little bit complicated releasing issue for my custom alert view having UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, release

I know the ARC in iOS 5 but I'm now developing pre-iOS 5 code style, and want to solve this problem by a manual release approach.

My only goal for this is to make a very handy custom alert view with UITextField.

I have a 'BigView' view that has many functions in it. And it can possibly generate many UIAlertView for many different situation on the display with that view. So I know the way use UIAlertViewDelegate for each alert view, but kind of experimentally try want to make this as like UIButton's 'addTarget'(actually it's UIControl's method).

Briefly,

This is in the part of 'BigView' class and my 'TextAlert' instance fired by a button for email gathering .

BigView.m

```
- (void)emailFeedback:(id)sender
{
    TextAlert *textAlert = [[TextAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter your email address"];
    [textAlert setTarget:self action:@selector(textAlertInputed:)];
//    [textAlert release];
}

- (void)textAlertInputed:(NSString *)text
{
    NSLog(@"text alert inputed, text: %@", text);
}
```

and these are full my TextAlert files.

TextAlert.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TextAlert : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    UIAlertView *alertView;
    UITextField *textField;
    id target;
    SEL action;
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
- (void)setTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

@end
```

TextAlert.m

```
#import "TextAlert.h"

@implementation TextAlert

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"beneath" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];
        CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 60);
        [alertView setTransform:myTransform];
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [alertView addSubview:textField];
        [alertView show];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [alertView release]; alertView = nil;
    [textField release]; textField = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setTarget:(id)_target action:(SEL)_action
{
    target = _target;
    action = _action;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [target performSelector:action withObject:textField.text];
}

@end
```

So my main problem is the releasing point of TextAlert instance in the 'BigView' as you can see the only comment part full codes above. Of course if I remove that comment out, I got crash for call for method of deallocated.

And I also get error make textAlert instance as autoreleased one.

For me, the only solution for this is to make the 'textAlert' object in the 'BigView' a member of 'BigView' not local object. But in that case, my initial goal for handy and lightweight approach for this is not satisfied, I think. And the 'BigView' has already many member instances so I don't want to add any more.

So any suggestions? Or It will be welcome any comment for this trying. I'm ready to hear any 
reproves to my insufficient code, really.

Thanks in advance,

MK

Comment: i think you should inherit from UIAlertView and not from NSObject and override/add the initWithTitle Method

Comment: @meccan "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't directly what you asked for, but could help you anyway.

Handling multiple `UIAlertViews` in a single `UIViewController` can be painful. When I ran into this problem, I found an alternative control on github, called [BlockAlertsAndActionSheets](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets). It uses blocks instead of delegates, the appearance can be fully customized (even to the default Apple-style) and there is also an "AlertView with an UITextField". Works good for me and I didn't have to reinvent that wheel! ;-)

Comment: OK, it's very handy component and I agree with yours and those project's concept of convenient using of UIAlertView. You gave me very nice link, appreciate it. I want to use this but don't know how can hand a inputed text in the BlockTextPromptAlertView instance out to master view without using it as member variable. In other words, when I use BlockTextPromptAlertView instance as a local, how can I get the text from that BlockTextPromptAlertView's block to my main area. I can guess only notification approach, but I think there seems to be more smart way for this. Thanks for all in advance.

Comment: Oh! I found the way interacting with UITextField in BlockTextPromptAlertView! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If everything works except your release problem you should only consider implementing public "show" method and private "dismiss" method (in your custom alert view).. In show method you should call [self retain] beside other things and on dismiss (add this target to button or whatever dismisses your view) call [self relese].

Comment: Yeah, I got your point but after [alert show] I need to get the inputed text from the alert. That means I need to open some place to get the text input event and remain some object globally to receive it. Yes, release problem is my main thing but 2)don't use global alert member 3)communicate with alert's member and master(object firing the alert) as a text or other object. Thank you your opinion and it helped me to see this more widely. As 'show' and 'dismiss' concept, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to achieve that text sending part. You could create a protocol and send a delegate to your alert view, you could send a "NSString **" and give it a copy of textfields string or just have some global link to object you want to send the text to.. Also I would suggest creating your own custom alert view from scratch with subclassing UIView. I already did that VERY successfully, but that is another topic..